# How to open a Photoshop file in Illusrator preserving effects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects

So, I have a logo which I made in Photoshop and it has a lot of effects. The logo itself is a shape, not a raster image, and I wanted to continue editing it in Illustrator but without the need of recreating it again (because it's not easy). Is there a way to open it in Illustrator with all the effects and stuff intact?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how many effects will transfer over but what you can do is "save as" as .EPS file. Then open that file in Illustrator. Go to the "Layers" palette and open up that layer and you'll see all the shapes grouped individually with the effects. For example, you'll see the vector circle and the drop shadow layer on its own. Sometimes depending on effect, it places that effect in a subgroup of the vector. Again, not sure how complex the logo is but hope that helps. Also, keep in mind "all effects" not editable at this point.

[image: Example of Vector circle and drop shadow (.EPS opened in Illustrator)]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try! Are the layer masks going to be there too?

Comment: Sort of but in funky kind of way. If you want to edit the shape you'll have limitations and the shape is married to the mask. Meaning the shape doesn't come in as a fully editable shape. And I haven't found a way to combine them as a sort compound path. I would play around with and see if it works for you. It might just be what you need but if you can rebuild in Illustrator, I would highly suggest that for a cleaner file. Good luck!